# &infin; not displaying inside span tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently having an issue with getting any HTML entity to display while inside a span. I am currently trying to get `&infin;` to show up if my object has no destroy date. If I move the entity outside the span it will appear. Below is the code before it is rendered:

```
<tr>
  <th>
    Deactivate Date
  </th>
  <td>
    <span edit>
      <%= text_field_tag 'destroy_date', @account_type.destroy_date %>
    </span>
    <span show>
      <%= @account_type.destroy_date.present? ? @account_type.destroy_date : '&infin;'.html_safe %>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is how the code is rendered if @account_types.destroy_date is not present.

```
<tr>
  <th>
    Deactivate Date
  </th>
  <td class="clickable">
    <span edit="" style="display: none;">
      <input id="destroy_date" name="destroy_date" type="text" last-value="" class="hasDatepicker">
    </span>
    <span show="" style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in a related .js file causing this issue.